# How to make VOIP application for Android phone?

Tags: php, android

I am currently working on a VoIP application. Can anyone tell me which server I use for audio, video calling and text messaging? I searched a lot, but not clear which one is easy to use and more reliable.

Comment: So you're not currently working, you're planning. You don't know the technologies you should use, even.

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow**. Have a look on the [Tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take a look at [What Questions Can I Ask Here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: you can find multiple SIP clients on the web to achieve this. All you to do is  to create SIP accounts and provide server ip to your users.

Comment: start here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

Comment: I have worked on design. I am stucked in that which server i use...... I do not found a proper path to make the project.

Comment: I have visited the developer android. but i am actually lacking in which server i use....

Answer (score 0):

For chat you can setup XMPP or FCM. for video call conference setup with WebRTC.

Hangout APIs are also available for both chat and Video call conference.

You can also opt 3rd party WebRTC SDK's like Vidyo.com etc

You can also setup your own XMPP and WebRTC server. though are protocols.